# How can I insert wordpress page title in any section of this page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to insert wordpress page title in any area of this page. Such as displaying page title in blog area of this page. Is their any code that I can use in text editor (blog editor) to displaying this title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a function in your functions.php file (in child theme if you have one).

```
function post_title_shortcode(){
    return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('post_title','post_title_shortcode');
```

You call it like this: `[post_title]`

Comment: Glad to be of help. Would you mind marking it 'answered' so that it may help others in the future? :)